# Taylor series for $\cot x$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Hi guys could you show me how to do the expansion of the Taylor series of $\cot x $ at the point $x=0$. My idea was to use $\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x} $ and I want to expand it to the second term because I have to find the limit of $\dfrac{x\cot x-1}{x^2}$ but when I do the expansion I get $\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{x}{2}$ instead of $\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{x}{3}$. Any idea why?

Comment: With what order?

Comment: Due to the $1/x$ term, technically it's not a Taylor series, although $x\cot x$ has one. What you want is a [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right  we use the equality
$$\cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
and since
$$\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}=\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)\right)$$
hence we expand and we find
$$\cot x=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)\right)\frac{1}{x}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)\right)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}+o(x)$$

Comment: @user109218 To find this result you can also use the division in ascending powers.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question , but how do you get from here 1/(x−(x^3)/6+o(x3)) to 1/x *(1+((x^2)/6)+o(x3))

Comment: We have
$$\frac{1}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^3)}$$ and use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+o(u^2)$$

Comment: I would never have thought about the second part. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider the Taylor expansion series for both $\cos{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ at $x=0$, separately. Then, divide term by term to obtain the Taylor series for $\cot{x}$.

Cheers!

Edit:

By using division term by term, I meant this:

$$ (1-x^2/2 + x^4/24 + O(x^6) : (x-x^3/6 + x^5/120 + O(x^6)) \approx 1/x-x/3,$$

being the rest of the **polynomial long division**:

$$r = -x^4/45 + O(x^6)$$

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...
$$\frac{(xcot x-1)}{x^2} = \frac{(x-\tan x)}{(x^2×\tan x)}$$
$$= \frac{(x-(x + (x^3)/3 + ....)}{(x^2)×\tan x} =\frac{-x^3×(1+2x^2/5+.....)}{(3×x^2×tan x)}$$
$$= \frac{-1}{(3×(\frac{tan x}{x})}$$

It will help , hopefully!!!

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math. Thank you.