# If $x\cot x=a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\cdots$, then $\frac{a_{2n}}{1!}-\frac{a_{2n-1}}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^na_0}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

If $x\cot x=a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\cdots$, then show that $$ \dfrac{a_{2n}}{1!}-\dfrac{a_{2n-2}}{3!}+\dfrac{a_{2n-4}}{5!}-\cdots+\dfrac{(-1)^na_{0}}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} $$
This problem is from the book "Higher Trigonometry by B.C DAS & N. MUKHERJEE". Unfortunately, there is no solution manual available on the internet so I have to post here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637169/taylor-series-for-cot-x/3744852#:~:text=You%20should%20consider%20the%20Taylor,Taylor%20series%20for%20cotx. may answer your question.

Comment: Write $(x\cot x)(\sin x) = x\cos x$. Now substitute into the LHS the series for $x\cot x$ with unknown coefficients and the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$. Perform the Cauchy product of the two power series. The result should agree with the Maclaurin series of $x\cos x$ on the RHS. Compare the coefficients of like powers of $x^{2n+1}$ and you are done.